# Infinispan with hanging threads in level 1 clean up

Tags: wildfly, infinispan, jgroups, wildfly-22

We are trying to upgrade from Wildfly 18 to 22 and are experiencing some trouble with threads left dangling in the jgroups thread group. When the number of threads reaches the default max number (200) everything stops up (naturally). This takes two to three days in our test environment.

In the thread dump we are left with 200 dangling threads that look like this:

```
at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@11.0.8/Native Method)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.base@11.0.8/LockSupport.java:234)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Signaller.block(java.base@11.0.8/CompletableFuture.java:1798)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(java.base@11.0.8/ForkJoinPool.java:3128)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(java.base@11.0.8/CompletableFuture.java:1868)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(java.base@11.0.8/CompletableFuture.java:2021)
at org.infinispan.util.concurrent.CompletableFutures.await(CompletableFutures.java:125)
at org.infinispan.util.concurrent.CompletionStages.join(CompletionStages.java:80)
at org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.L1NonTxInterceptor.lambda$handleDataWriteCommand$10(L1NonTxInterceptor.java:399)
at org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.L1NonTxInterceptor$$Lambda$1806/0x0000000841ace040.apply(Unknown Source)
at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.QueueAsyncInvocationStage.invokeQueuedHandlers(QueueAsyncInvocationStage.java:125)
at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.QueueAsyncInvocationStage.accept(QueueAsyncInvocationStage.java:88)
at org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.QueueAsyncInvocationStage.accept(QueueAsyncInvocationStage.java:33)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(java.base@11.0.8/CompletableFuture.java:859)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(java.base@11.0.8/CompletableFuture.java:837)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(java.base@11.0.8/CompletableFuture.java:506)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(java.base@11.0.8/CompletableFuture.java:2073)
at org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.PrimaryOwnerOnlyCollector.primaryResult(PrimaryOwnerOnlyCollector.java:30)
at org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.TriangleDistributionInterceptor.lambda$forwardToPrimary$6(TriangleDistributionInterceptor.java:526)
at org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.TriangleDistributionInterceptor$$Lambda$1953/0x0000000841d51040.apply(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(java.base@11.0.8/CompletableFuture.java:930)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(java.base@11.0.8/CompletableFuture.java:907)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(java.base@11.0.8/CompletableFuture.java:506)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(java.base@11.0.8/CompletableFuture.java:2073)
at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.AbstractRequest.complete(AbstractRequest.java:67)
at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.impl.SingleTargetRequest.onResponse(SingleTargetRequest.java:45)
at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.impl.RequestRepository.addResponse(RequestRepository.java:52)
at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.processResponse(JGroupsTransport.java:1402)
at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.processMessage(JGroupsTransport.java:1305)
at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.access$300(JGroupsTransport.java:131)
at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport$ChannelCallbacks.up(JGroupsTransport.java:1445)
at org.jgroups.JChannel.up(JChannel.java:784)
at org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.up(ProtocolStack.java:913)
at org.jgroups.protocols.FRAG3.up(FRAG3.java:165)
at org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.up(FlowControl.java:343)
at org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.up(FlowControl.java:343)
at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS.up(GMS.java:876)
at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STABLE.up(STABLE.java:243)
at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.deliverMessage(UNICAST3.java:1049)
at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.addMessage(UNICAST3.java:772)
at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.handleDataReceived(UNICAST3.java:753)
at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.up(UNICAST3.java:405)
at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2.up(NAKACK2.java:592)
at org.jgroups.protocols.VERIFY_SUSPECT.up(VERIFY_SUSPECT.java:132)
at org.jgroups.protocols.FailureDetection.up(FailureDetection.java:186)
at org.jgroups.protocols.FD_SOCK.up(FD_SOCK.java:254)
at org.jgroups.protocols.MERGE3.up(MERGE3.java:281)
at org.jgroups.protocols.Discovery.up(Discovery.java:300)
at org.jgroups.protocols.TP.passMessageUp(TP.java:1396)
at org.jgroups.util.SubmitToThreadPool$SingleMessageHandler.run(SubmitToThreadPool.java:87)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@11.0.8/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@11.0.8/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.8/Thread.java:834)
```

These threads are hanging on a CompletableFuture.get(...) with a infinispan-hardcoded timeout of 24 hours. This is probably not something that should happen, which is confirmed by the exception we get when the timeout is finally reached:

```
2021-03-03 09:00:46,638 ERROR [org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.InvocationContextInterceptor] (jgroups-263,xxxxxxxxxxxx) ISPN000136: Error executing command ReadWriteKeyCommand on Cache 'sessionmanager.session', writing keys [xxxx#xxxxxx]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This should never happen!
        at org.infinispan@11.0.8.Final//org.infinispan.util.concurrent.CompletableFutures.await(CompletableFutures.java:127)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.8.Final//org.infinispan.util.concurrent.CompletionStages.join(CompletionStages.java:80)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.8.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.L1NonTxInterceptor.lambda$handleDataWriteCommand$10(L1NonTxInterceptor.java:399)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.8.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.QueueAsyncInvocationStage.invokeQueuedHandlers(QueueAsyncInvocationStage.java:125)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.8.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.QueueAsyncInvocationStage.accept(QueueAsyncInvocationStage.java:88)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.8.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.QueueAsyncInvocationStage.accept(QueueAsyncInvocationStage.java:33)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.8.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.PrimaryOwnerOnlyCollector.primaryResult(PrimaryOwnerOnlyCollector.java:30)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.8.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.distribution.TriangleDistributionInterceptor.lambda$forwardToPrimary$6(TriangleDistributionInterceptor.java:526)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:930)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:907)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.8.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.AbstractRequest.complete(AbstractRequest.java:67)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.8.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.impl.SingleTargetRequest.onResponse(SingleTargetRequest.java:45)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.8.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.impl.RequestRepository.addResponse(RequestRepository.java:52)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.8.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.processResponse(JGroupsTransport.java:1402)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.8.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.processMessage(JGroupsTransport.java:1305)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.8.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.access$300(JGroupsTransport.java:131)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.8.Final//org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport$ChannelCallbacks.up(JGroupsTransport.java:1445)
        at org.jgroups@4.2.10.Final//org.jgroups.JChannel.up(JChannel.java:784)
        at org.jgroups@4.2.10.Final//org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.up(ProtocolStack.java:913)
        at org.jgroups@4.2.10.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.FRAG3.up(FRAG3.java:165)
        at org.jgroups@4.2.10.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.up(FlowControl.java:343)
        at org.jgroups@4.2.10.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.up(FlowControl.java:343)
        at org.jgroups@4.2.10.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS.up(GMS.java:876)
        at org.jgroups@4.2.10.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STABLE.up(STABLE.java:243)
        at org.jgroups@4.2.10.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.deliverMessage(UNICAST3.java:1049)
        at org.jgroups@4.2.10.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.addMessage(UNICAST3.java:772)
        at org.jgroups@4.2.10.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.handleDataReceived(UNICAST3.java:753)
        at org.jgroups@4.2.10.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.up(UNICAST3.java:405)
        at org.jgroups@4.2.10.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2.up(NAKACK2.java:592)
        at org.jgroups@4.2.10.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.VERIFY_SUSPECT.up(VERIFY_SUSPECT.java:132)
        at org.jgroups@4.2.10.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.FailureDetection.up(FailureDetection.java:186)
        at org.jgroups@4.2.10.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.FD_SOCK.up(FD_SOCK.java:254)
        at org.jgroups@4.2.10.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.MERGE3.up(MERGE3.java:281)
        at org.jgroups@4.2.10.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.Discovery.up(Discovery.java:300)
        at org.jgroups@4.2.10.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.TP.passMessageUp(TP.java:1396)
        at org.jgroups@4.2.10.Final//org.jgroups.util.SubmitToThreadPool$SingleMessageHandler.run(SubmitToThreadPool.java:87)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(CompletableFuture.java:1886)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2021)
        at org.infinispan@11.0.8.Final//org.infinispan.util.concurrent.CompletableFutures.await(CompletableFutures.java:125)
        ... 44 more
```

Have anyone encountered a similar problem? What can possibly lead to this situation?